# Action dispatch for a combat class

Tags: python, object-oriented, battle-simulation

My problem is that I have a piece of code logic that I'm having trouble fitting into an OO approach, and I was looking for design patterns so that the following code would no longer rely on the ugly

> if class is of type A do X else do Y

In Python, we can say I have three "fighting method" classes, `class Fight`, `class Manoeuvre`, and `class Dodge`.

I also have a control class that takes two inputs, `attackMode` and `defendMode`. The inputs will always be objects whose classes extend from or are of one of the above three.

The piece of script causing issue is as follows:

```
from random import Random

# Following are example "Action" objects which are to be compared
# For results

class Action:
    "Base Action all others inherit from"
    __random = Random()

    def __init__(self):
       self.health = 100 

    @classmethod
    def getSuccess(cls):
        return cls.__random.randint(-2,3)

class Dodge(Action):
    def __init__(self):
       super(Dodge, self).__init__() 
class Attack(Action):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Attack, self).__init__() 

    def performActionOn(self, subject, sucessLevel=0):
        damage = 5 if successLevel > 1 else 3
        subject.health -= damage

class Manoeuvre(Action):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Manoeuvre, self).__init__() 

    def performActionOn(self, subject, successLevel=0):
        pass

# Following is the results configuration

class CombatControl:
    def fight(self, actionAttack, actionDefend):

        if isinstance(actionDefend, Dodge):
            __attackDodge(actionAttack, actionDefend)
        else: 
            __attackAttack(actionAttack, actionDefend) 

    def __attackAttack(self, attack, defend):
        """
        " Defender Attacks back
        """
        resultAttack = attack.getSuccess()
        resultDefend = defend.getSuccess()

        # Both failed. No action.
        if resultAttack < 0 and resultDefend < 0: 
            return
        # Attack wins or draw
        elif resultAttack >= resultDefend:
            attack.performActionOn(defend, successLevel=resultAttack)
        # Defend wins
        else:
            # Does not get damage bonus
            defend.performActionOn(attack)

    def __attackDodge(self, attack, defend):
        """
        " Defender is dodging
        """
        resultAttack = attack.getSuccess()
        resultDefend = defend.getSuccess()

        if resultAttack > resultDefend:
            attack.performActionOn(actionAttack, successLevel=resultAttack)
```

As you can see in the final case, there's a bit of jiggery-pokery going on where resolution is based upon the type of class. This is undesired.

Ideally I'd want a solution which would allow for something more polymorphic. The structure can change however required if it leads to an elegant solution, as long as the results are the same.

Comment: The way you described the situation, multimethod seems to be best fit. Have you taken a look at multimethod (for example, pypi package of the same name)? If you have a lot of situations like that, maybe nonOOP solution like rules engine and rules  would fit the bill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that came to mind was further encapsulation of the fight mechanics. One thing I did have to change was how success was handled; now it's a member of each action subclass and is given a new value each time `Controller.fight` is called.

The other part necessary to this approach was the implementation of a action mode (offensive or defensive) so that actions like `Dodge` would know what to do.

```
import random

OFFENSIVE = 0
DEFENSIVE = 1


class Action(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Action, self).__init__()
        self.health = 100
        self.success = 0
        self.nextSuccess()

    def nextSuccess(self):
        self.success = random.randint(-2, 3)

    def performOn(self, subject, success):
        pass


class Dodge(Action):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dodge, self).__init__()

    def performOn(self, subject):
        if mode == DEFENSIVE and subject.success > self.success:
            subject.performOn(subject, success=subject.success)


class Attack(Action):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Attack, self).__init__()

    def performOn(self, subject, mode):
        if self.success < 0 and subject.success < 0:
            return
        if mode == OFFENSIVE and self.success >= subject.success:
            subject.health -= 5 if success > 1 else 3
        elif mode == DEFENSIVE and self.success > subject.success:
            subject.health -= 3


class Manoeuvre(Action):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Attack, self).__init__()


class Controller:

    def fight(offense, defense):
        offensive = offense.nextSuccess()
        defensive = defense.nextSuccess()
        offense.performOn(defense, OFFENSIVE)
        defense.performOn(offense, DEFENSIVE)
```

As far as I can tell this does what the original script did. If there are any tweaks that need to be made, let me know!